# ImagickException: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643

Tags: php, image-resizing, imagick

I am using the following imagick script to resize images:

```
$image = new Imagick($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
$image->resizeImage(980,0, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9);
$image->writeImage($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
$image->destroy();
```

The image is the same directory in which the file containing this script is present.I used Imagick on my Bigrock linux server and it worked perfect.But it isnt working on my local machine.

How can i make imagick get images from the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used absolute path of the image and it worked. Try to use image like below:

```
$image = new Imagick('C:\xampp\htdocs\folder-name\image.png');
```